# Security Update?

Tags: updating

Drupal gives me the following message:

> There is a security update available for your version of Drupal. To ensure the security of your server, you should update immediately! See the available updates page for more information and to install your missing updates.

But when I click on available updates, it says:

> Manual updates required
>
> Updates of Drupal core are not supported at this time.

So what should I do?

Comment: If you're updating to Drupal 7.32, be sure to check this post: https://www.drupal.org/PSA-2014-003

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update modules directly through the admin panel, but Drupal cannot update itself (at least not yet). So you will have to do that upgrade through the filesystem by uploading the new Drupal core files in place of the old ones, or (preferably) the command line with Drush.

Here is an instructional page:

- [Upgrading from previous versions](https://www.drupal.org/upgrade)

You can also find guidance in the [UPGRADE.txt](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/upgrade.txt/7) file in the Drupal core package.

If you are familiar with the command line, you can use [Drush](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush) to do updates which makes it very quick and easy. If you are not familiar with Drush, here is a [beginner's guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/a-beginner-s-guide-to-drush-the-drupal-shell).

Comment: So when I update Drupal,what will happen to the modules that I have installed?

Comment: Leave them in the sites folder and they should be fine. (See the full description above for more detailed info)